# Balancing between confidence and arrogance

Tags: etiquette, application

People always advise me that I should focus on my achievements when I write a mail for, say research asistanship because people receive a lot of emails and want to know why they should pick me.

However, I do not want to be seen as too confident or arrogant. Is there any way to know when is too much?

Best regards.

Comment: "I am ambitious, highly motivated and conscientious" vs. "at high school I build a miniature rocket, driven by self-distilled hydrazine and reaching an altitude of 30 miles (experiment was carried out with due permissions from the local and state governments). Which is a claim and which is an achievement?

Comment: I agree with @CaptainEmacs, I think the principle, as they say, is "show, not tell", give evidence/examples (i.e. facts) that make you great, but don't tell them you are great (i.e. adjectives).